# How do I declare gemspec dependency as >= 3.1 but less than < 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am making changes to my ruby gem to make it asset pipeline compatible. In my gemspec I want to say that it requires rails version `> 3.1` and `< 4`. How do I do that.

currently this is what I have.

`s.add_dependency("rails", ">= 3.1")`

But this is not ideal. This is saying that it will also work with `rails 4.0` which might not be true.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the pessimistic operator `~>`

Using the pessimistic operator, you could write

`s.add_dependency("rails", "~> 3.1")`

which is equivalent to `'>= 3.1', '< 4.0'`